# How to fill NaN values with the last good observation using java spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, data-science

i am trying to fill NaN values with the last good observation.

I am not using DataFrame, just reading a dat file with sparkcontext.

[image: example of the data]

In my example all of the NaN values should be with the values of 104.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out (or replace) NaN values from a Dataset using the [DataFrameNaFunctions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html) object:

Example:

```
Dataset<Row> yourDataSet = sparkSession.createDataFrame(yourJavaRDDCollection, yourSchema);
Dataset<Row> dfNaNFilter = new DataFrameNaFunctions(yourDataSet);

// If you want to remove all of them:
Dataset<Row> nonNaNValues = dfNaNFilter.drop();

// If you want to replace them with a numeric value (e.g. 104):
Dataset<Row> replacedNaNValues = dfNaNFilter.fill(104);
```